# Which House was Moaning Myrtle From?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

I've just read Sorcerer's Stone or Philosopher's Stone with my daughter and watched the movie and we are now beginning Chamber of Secrets.  As my husband and I were watching the movie (to decide if it would be too scary for her or not after reading the book,) I got to thinking about it and other than Mrs. Norris I believe all the Basilisk victims were from Gryffindor - in the movie.  Collin Creevy, Hermione - even the ghost was Sr. Nicholas.

Of course there were more victims in the book I was not remembering, but it made me wonder if Moaning Myrtle was also from G house (just coincidentally and as a curiosity).

Do the books say anywhere?

Comment: Penelope Clearwater was a Ravenclaw Prefect and Justin Finch-Fletchley was Hufflepuff, both were attacked, so the victims weren't all Gryffindor.

Comment: Thanks.  Like I said, I may have been forgetting some one.  Edit made to reflect your information.

Comment: Myrtle was in Ravenclaw, I'd answer instead of commenting, but I don't have the canon quote to seal the deal.

Comment: @MajorStackings: What is your non-canon quote? It'd be great to hear anyway :)

Comment: @Omega The best I could come up with was a HP Wikia page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ravenclaw), Myrtle was a member of Ravenclaw. Scroll down to the known Ravenclaw images.

Comment: If you click to her page, then look at her sidebar, it has "Ravenclaw" with a reference to a FAQ on Rowling's site - that apparently no longer exists...

Comment: It's customary to include a quote from the link, even is it's short, just incase the link ever goes bad. :)

Answer (score 26):

As per [J.K.Rowling FAQ from jkrowling.com via Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20070724184202/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=117), Ravenclaw.

> **What houses were Tonks and Myrtle in?**
>
> Hufflepuff and Ravenclaw respectively.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Major Stackings openly admitted that he had no better source than Wikia.

Comment: I'm so sorry Rowling's site is no longer there.  It was beautifully done and while Pottermore is great and all, there was just something **really cool** about her desk, finding things in the rubbish bin, seeing the "family tree" etc. etc.